# need to access value in hiera.yaml

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I need help on accessing hiera variable value in hiera.yaml file. Suppose I have a hiera.yaml file with the contents:

```
variable1: 'abc'<br>
variable2: "%{variable1}/xyz"
```

I mean I want to access/substitute variable1 value in hiera itself. How we can do this?

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: use a yaml library in the language of your choice, open the yaml file and read it in, modify the in memory representation of the yaml and then write out the whole thing again

Comment: I think I was not able to explain the question. Is it possible to replace the value of variable1 so that I can get the variable2 value as "abc/xyz" in hiera.yaml automatically?

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question. It can be achieved as:

variable2: "%{hiera('variable1')}/xyz"

This is working fine for me with Hiera version 1.3.4 and puppet version: 3.8.4

This is documented on the Puppet/Hiera website under [Interpolation Tokens, Variables, and Lookup Functions](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/variables.html)